# Error while installing libapache2-mod-wsgi on linux

Tags: django, apache

**easy_install libapache2-mod-wsgi**

```
No local packages or download links found for libapache2modwsgi
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('libapache2mod                                                                             wsgi')
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libapache2-mod-wsgi is not a python package. You should install it via your distribution package manager. For example, if you are in a debian based distribution:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Or if you are working with Python 3

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```